# Is there a sequel or prequel to Phillips Jose Farmers "The Unreasoning Mask"?

Tags: books, philip-jose-farmer

I have read this book some time ago and I never could find a sequel,  prequel or any related titles.  Does anyone know if any other books in this series exist or if there is a series at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not belong to a series, sorry. Is a standalone novel.

If you want or need some kind of reference to prove it, just check any reviews of the novel, like [this one](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/845599.The_Unreasoning_Mask), or Amazon's or similar. See how people say that

> [...] of his stand alone sf novels, this is one of his best.

or

> Farmer is best known for the 'Riverworld' series, this book does not belong in that series, but it is a major work of sci-fi.

So there you go.